# passing data from activity to fragment in android studio kotlin(not duplicate, those method is not working)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments

I am having an activity called Image activity inside it there are 2 fragments called image_display and image_change fragment, for image_activity I am getting data from an adapter(using getIntent), and it's working fine up to here. so I want to send the data
(i.e URL) to the fragment but my method is not working.

my image_activity code is like this

```
    class ImageActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image)

       var gi = getIntent()
        var url = gi.getStringExtra("url")
        val fragment = FragmentDisplayImage.newInstance(url.toString())

        Toast.makeText(this,url , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        var manager =supportFragmentManager
        manager.beginTransaction().commit()
    }
 }
```

and my FramentImage.kt is like

```
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "url"



class FragmentDisplayImage : Fragment() {
    
    private var param1: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {


            param1 = it.getString("url")
            var image= view?.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.Fragimage)
            Picasso.get().load(param1).resize(700, 700).centerCrop().into(image);
            Toast.makeText(context, param1.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()


        }

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_image, container, false)
    }

    companion object {

        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String) =
            FragmentDisplayImage().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)

                }
            }
    }
}
```

but still, I can't get my url here on the adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think so you're not starting your fragment.
You have just created fragment object but never opened it using manager.

Please updated your **ImageActivity** code as follow:

```
    var gi = getIntent()
    var url = gi.getStringExtra("url")
    val fragment = FragmentDisplayImage.newInstance(url.toString())

    val manager: FragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
    val transaction: FragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment)
    transaction.addToBackStack(null)
    transaction.commit()
```

where `R.id.container` will be Layout inside `activity_image` where you want to put your fragment.

your `activity_image` should have

```
<FrameLayout
  android:id="@+id/container"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: yes tried this method also but, its getting back to home screen, when i click on image(there is a image list i i click on it new activity will open which is having this fragment)